# visualization tool for mobile (tablet)

Tags: android, opengl-es, visualization, tablet

I have a project for visualizing some data on tablet. I'll probably use android for developing the application but I have no idea that how could I visualize the real time data ?

which tools are available on android for doing this ? I noticed that I can use OpenGL ES but then I know nothing of this and it's quite complicated for me . Is there any other simple tool that could get the real time data and visualize it ?

we have a basic Matlab/Simulink visualization but need a better visualization.

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are different options, but two commonly used visualization frameworks which are also available in Android are Processing ([Processing for Android](http://wiki.processing.org/w/Android)) and [d3.js](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/) (which is a Javascript framework you could use in a `WebView` if you are 3.0 or above. The Android browser does not support SVG below 3.0.

Answer (score 0):

You can use VES the OpenGL ES rendering toolkit from Kitware: http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VES