# android app for visualizing real time data

Tags: android, apache-flex, opengl-es-2.0

I want to build an android application that visualize some real time data , to get the position of objects and update it in real time and give me a simple animation .

I studied OpenGL ES for couple of days but it seems quite complicated . somebody here suggest processing in this topic , but I dont think it fits to my needs .[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9839451/visualization-tool-for-mobile-tablet)

any idea ?

Comment: What sort of data is this? How do you want to visualise it?

Comment: it's some sensor data , we set a UDP communication channel to get the data from a car and then visualize it . like the place of the car that will updated the whole time, different sensors in car and outside it . we decide to do 2D visualization right now .

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the link you posted looks like a good start. I would suggest the JS one, which seemed to give pretty good results.

Comment: Actually I'm working with processing and do not test JS now . But I'm not sure yet that any of these too could do what I want . Importing some Matlab logfile which includes some position for object and then the visualization tool should draw that object on android phone using that log file . seems Open Gl ES is the best thing I can use . any other ideas?